# How to use [for] to list all elements in 2 dimensional NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to make calculation on 2 dimensional `NSArray`. I don't figure out how to scroll through `NSArray`. As I understand `NSArray` is only 1 dimensional. So I suppose that have to scroll through rows and convert each row to `NSArray` again. And from it extract elements with index of column inside. 
I can not figure out how to use `for` to complete that operation.

My code is below

```
for (id object in myArray) {
    if([object[6] intValue] == 1){
        sumAmount += [object[3] intValue];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "two dimensional" array is just an array of arrays, so you nest your `for` loops like this:

```
for (NSArray *row in myArray) {
    for (id object in row) {
        // do something with object, such as...
        sumAmount += [object intValue];
    }
}
```

Comment: 10x, I know that, but I not figure out how to nest 2 NSArrays and how properly cast them.

Comment: Arrays are objects, so make an array of arrays like any other array of objects. One way is `+arrayWithObjects:`, passing in the arrays you want (e.g. an array for each row). You shouldn't need to cast anything if you know what type you saved in each row. If the objects in rows are strings, for example, use `NSString*` instead of `id` in the inner `for` loop above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two for loop like this:

```
for(int row = 0; row < NUM_OF_ROWS; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < NUM_OF_COL; col++){
        element = myArray[row][col];
    }
}
```

Just convert the code to match your data structure.